# Iterative function issue

Tags: java, string, function, jbutton, file-handling

Im having some issues with a function that I have written. The function basically takes a file and a string into the method as parameters and searches the file for that string and replaces it with "".

```
public void removeReminder(File a, String search) throws IOException {

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", a.getParentFile());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        line = line.replace(search, "");
        pw.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
    pw.close();

    a.delete();

    tempFile.renameTo(a);
}
```

I then have 3 text files that I need to run this method for. Below is the code where i run the function.

```
removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    // TODO
                    try {


                    String names = reminderNameField.getText();
                    String date = reminderDate.getText();
                    String details = reminderDetailsField.getText();

                    File fileName = new File("reminderNames.txt");
                    File fileDate = new File("reminderDate.txt");
                    File fileDetails = new File("reminderDetails.txt");


                        removeReminder(fileName, names);
                        removeReminder(fileDate, date);
                        removeReminder(fileDetails, details);
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I dont know why this isnt working. It works for the first iteration (e.g removeReminder(fileName, names);) But it doesnt work for the other ones, it seems to just ignore them :s can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: can u be more specific about "doesn't work"? Is the file empty?

Comment: It empties the first file with " removeReminder(fileName, names);" But it doesnt do anything for the other files. It removes the string from the fileName, but leaves the strings in fileDate + fileDetails. :s

Comment: Check what delete() returns. If false, it means unsuccessful delete which cause the rename to fail and you'll be looking at the original files. Try to write results in new file with passed in filename with .res suffix. And don't delete and rename. Check results.

Comment: Yeah it seems to fail on the delete side. It cant delete the files therefore its just showing me the original files, how can i get around this?

Comment: Maybe you have another process accessing that file? If on windows, you can use the process explorer utility in the sysinternal suite and find which process is accessing the file. The other way is as suggested b4 to write to a different file like File temp=new File(a.getParentFile(),a.getName()+".res")

Comment: That was it Anonymous, stupidly earlier in my code, it opens the file to display the variables in a text field and I hadnt closed the bufferedReader which displayed them therefore my program wouldnt delete the file and rename it since it was already open. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I always flush printwriter. Try flushing PrintWriter before calling close().

```
pw.flush();
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck :S, I just cant understand why it would work for the first call of the method, but not for the next two?